# How can i set the text for a label in razor page using "if" condition?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have the following

```
<label for="source" class="col-md-2 control-label">SourceFolder</label>
```

I have a value in the javascript , filed is called eventtype.
I am trying to do the following

```
<label for="source" class="col-md-2 control-label">eventtype == 2 ? SourceDirectory 
 :SourceFolder</label>
```

How can i do this using ternary operator ?

Comment: Do you want to use Javascript or Razor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For eventtype is a js variable,you can only use if in js.Here is a demo:

```
<label id="myLable" for="source" class="col-md-2 control-label">SourceFolder</label>
```

js:

```
<script>
var eventtype=2;
$(function() {
            var data = eventtype == 2 ? "SourceDirectory" : "SourceFolder";
            document.getElementById("myLable").innerHTML = data;
        })
</script>
```